# Adding element to array via UIKit modal not working in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, getuikit

I have a table on my page that displays an array of "currency" objects:

```
<tbody> 
   <tr v-for="currency in currencies" v-bind:key="currency.Name">
   <td class="uk-width-medium">{{currency.Enabled}}</td>
   <td class="uk-width-medium">{{currency.Name}}</td>
   <td class="uk-width-medium">{{currency.MinDepositAmount}}</td>
...
```

I have a "+" button that displays a modal popup where the user can fill in values.

```
<payment-method-currency-modal id="paymentMethodCurrencyPopup" :currency="newCurrency"  @onSave="addCurrency" title="Add currency">
```

When the "Save" button on the dialog is clicked, the dialog is closed and the following method is called on the parent:

```
  addCurrency() {
          if (!this.currencies) {
              console.log("currencies was undefined. creating.");
              this.currencies = [];
          }
          this.currencies.push(this.newCurrency);
          this.newCurrency = { MinorUnitMultiplier: 100, Enabled: true };
          console.log(this.currencies);
      },
```

The console logs are only for my debugging purposes. First the function checks if `this.currencies` is undefined, because in the beginning it could be. If it's undefined, it sets it to an empty array. Then it pushes the element (`newCurrency` object) to the array and resets `newCurrency` to a default new object.

Here's how the code (mis)behaves:

1. I add element with name "a". I get the message that `currencies` was undefined and was created. Object "a" is then pushed to the array. **It is not displayed in the table.**
2. I add element "b". I once again get the message that currencies is undefined (and if I put a breakpoint there I see that it is indeed undefined. `currencies` is then initialized and object "b" is added. **It IS displayed in my table**.
3. I add element "c". My `addCurrency` method now tells me that `currencies` is an array with one object - "a". Object "c" is then added, and the resulting array contains two objects - "a" and "c". However the table still only shows object "b".
4. I add element "d". My array now contains "a", "c", and "d". The table still only shows "b".

No matter how many objects I add, the array used by `addCurrency` will have the second element omitted ("a","c","d","e","f","g","h"...) and the table will only display the second element. This behavior, while strange, is consistent - no matter how many times I run the experiment, it behaves the same.

What might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out what is happening. The parent component (the one I'm adding the table to) is also an editor component, which can be triggered in two situations - adding a new item and editing an existing one. And it turns out that my predecessor used two different instances of the component for these two usecases. And for whatever reason, the `addCurrency` function for "b" is being hit on the instance I called the popup from, while all the other elements get sent to the other instance.

First thing I tried when I realized this was I assigned unique keys to each instance of my component. This didn't help. I'll google around for a solution, if I don't find one I'll try to rework the code to only use one instance of my component.