# vuejs emits from a component are landing on the wrong instance of parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an existing component, which has a table of settings for payment methods. These can be added or edited via a modal popup component. I'm adding an editable list of currencies to each payment method, with a table and an editor popup (essentially recreating the same functionality one level down)

The parent component actually uses two different instances of the PaymentMethods component - one for adding a new PaymentMethod, and one for editing existing ones. This is done because they are given different parameters via their props.

Here's some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
<button ... >New Payment Method</button> // triggers popup1
<payment-methods-modal id="popup1" ... > // for new items
<table ....>
<tr v-for="paymentMethods">
...
<td>
<button ...>Edit</button> // triggers popup2
</td>
<table>
<payment-methods-modal id="popup2"... > // for editing existing items
```

As I described here
[Adding element to array via UIKit modal not working in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624142/adding-element-to-array-via-uikit-modal-not-working-in-vuejs)

I have added a table to the PaymentMethodsModal, and a button that opens a new dialog, "CurrenciesModal". This dialog emits an "onSave" event. The PaymentMethodsModal handles it by adding/updating its own array of currencies (so far just adding, I haven't gotten to updating)

Problem is, since I have 2 instances of PaymentMethodsModal, Vue gets confused as to which instance
of PaymentMethodsModal should handle the event. As a result, all but one call of the handler is triggered on the incorrect instance - not the one I opened CurrenciesModal from. For some reason it's always the second one. If I enter items "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", the correct instance of CurrenciesModal will have "b", and the other one will have "a", "c", "d", "e".

When I found out, I tried the only thing I could think of that could possibly help Vue sort out its instances - I gave every instance of PaymentMethodsModal and CurrenciesModal a unique id. It didn't help. Is this a bug in Vue, or is there something that can be done?

I'm using Vue.js v2.6.10

Edit: by popular request, here is the code that emits/handles the events:

1. PaymentMethodsModal:
   Markup for my Currency modal:

   <payment-method-currency-modal key="a2" id="paymentMethodCurrencyPopup" :currency="newCurrency" @onSave="addCurrency" title="Add currency">

Method handling the event:

```
addCurrency(cur) {
          if (!this.currencies) {
              console.log("currencies was undefined. creating.");
              this.currencies = [];
          }
          this.currencies.push(cur);
          this.newCurrency = { MinorUnitMultiplier: 100, Enabled: true };
          console.log(this.currencies);
      },
```

2. the CurrenciesModal - emitting the event:

   <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-modal-close uk-border-rounded" type="button" @click="onSave" :disabled="!isValid()">

   methods: {
   onSave() {
   this.$emit("onSave", this.currency);
   },

Comment: Post your template that shows the subscription to event, and code that's emitting the event.

Comment: _"Is this a bug in Vue?"_ Very unprobable, the community is so large, this would have happened to others and would have been addressed. Please show a minimal version of your code that still contains enough info for us to see how events are emitted, where you handle them, how you declare the props on these components (where do these props come from? Do you use Vuex?). This will give us more context to try and help you

Comment: There is definitely something that can be done ;). Can you add some more code 1) on how you emit the events and 2) how you catch it?

Comment: I added the code